# Probability function of two coin flips, is $P=\frac{1}{4}$ valid?

Tags: probability, self-study

The probability function of a countable set $\Omega$ is a function $P:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t.

$$P(w)≥0, \forall w\in \Omega$$
$$\sum_{w\in\Omega}P(w)=1$$

For two coin tosses, i.e. $\Omega = \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$, isn't

$$P(w)=\frac{1}{4}, \forall w\in \Omega$$
a fully valid probability function?

But how does this affect the distribution of some r.v. $X: \Omega \rightarrow S$, which is defined as:

$$P_X(s)=\sum_{w:X(w)=s}P(w), s\in S$$

This would imply that:

$$P_X=1$$

But is this reasonable?

Comment: If you are saying $\displaystyle \sum_{s \in S} P_X^{}(s) = 1$ then this is correct and corresponds to your earlier  $\displaystyle\sum_{w\in\Omega}P(w)=1$

Comment: @Henry That's the same thing if the r.v. $X$ is defined for all $s \in S$, which must always be the case?

Comment: If $X$ is a function $\Omega \to S$ then presumably so.

Comment: What's this kind of constant distribution called? Uniform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying $\displaystyle \sum_{s \in S} P_X^{}(s) = 1$ then this is correct and corresponds to your earlier  $\displaystyle\sum_{w\in\Omega}P(w)=1$.

But if you are saying $P_X^{}(s) = 1$ for all $s \in S$ then consider $X$ being the number of heads, so $P_X^{}(0)=P(TT)=\frac14$, $P_X^{}(1)=P(HT)+P(TH)=\frac12$, $P_X^{}(2)=P(HH)=\frac14$.